# Unable to find a match in MongoDB query

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

```
> db.inventory.find( )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45087"), "item" : "journal", "qty" : 25, "status" : "A", "size" : { "h" : 14, "w" : 21, "uom" : "cm" }, "tags" : [ "blank", "red" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45088"), "item" : "notebook", "qty" : 50, "status" : "A", "size" : { "h" : 8.5, "w" : 11, "uom" : "in" }, "tags" : [ "red", "blank" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45089"), "item" : "paper", "qty" : 10, "status" : "D", "size" : { "h" : 8.5, "w" : 11, "uom" : "in" }, "tags" : [ "red", "blank", "plain" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508a"), "item" : "planner", "qty" : 0, "status" : "D", "size" : { "h" : 22.85, "w" : 30, "uom" : "cm" }, "tags" : [ "blank", "red" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508b"), "item" : "postcard", "qty" : 45, "status" : "A", "size" : { "h" : 10, "w" : 15.25, "uom" : "cm" }, "tags" : [ "blue" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04608"), "item" : "journal", "qty" : 25, "tags" : [ "blank", "red" ], "dim_cm" : [ 14, 21 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04609"), "item" : "notebook", "qty" : 50, "tags" : [ "red", "blank" ], "dim_cm" : [ 14, 21 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460a"), "item" : "paper", "qty" : 100, "tags" : [ "red", "blank", "plain" ], "dim_cm" : [ 14, 21 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460b"), "item" : "planner", "qty" : 75, "tags" : [ "blank", "red" ], "dim_cm" : [ 22.85, 30 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460c"), "item" : "postcard", "qty" : 45, "tags" : [ "blue" ], "dim_cm" : [ 10, 15.25 ] }
> 
> db.inventory.find( { item: 'journal', qty: '25' }   )
>
```

item: 'journal' with qty '25' is the first item. Why isn't it being shown?

Here is a similar query which is working as per them: https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb-exercises/mongodb-exercise-22.php

```
db.restaurants.find( 
                {
                 "grades.date": ISODate("2014-08-11T00:00:00Z"), 
                 "grades.grade":"A" , 
                 "grades.score" : 11
                }, 
                {"restaurant_id" : 1,"name":1,"grades":1}
             );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qty` is a number and you're trying to find a string, try:

```
db.inventory.find( { item: 'journal', qty: 25 }   )
```

([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#type-bracketing))

> For most data types, however, comparison operators only perform comparisons on documents where the BSON type of the target field matches the type of the query operand.